# Illegal assignment pattern. the number of elements (1) does not match with type's wirth (2). in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am attaching the case with it.

```
module top;
    reg [1:0] arr; 

    reg [2:0] arr_asgn;

    assign arr = {'{ default: arr_asgn[2] }};
endmodule
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me: have you picked a particular solution (Y) to a particular problem (X) and now have a problem with (Y)? What is X? What problem are you actually trying to solve by typing `{'{ default: arr_asgn[2] }}`? For example, if X is "make every bit of `arr` equal to bit 2 of `arr_asgn`, then how about trying `assign arr = {$bits(arr){arr_asgn[2]}};`. You can write fortran in any language, but perhaps you cannot write VHDL in SytemVerilog. :-) And actually, you'd need VHDL-2008 to write this in VHDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntactically incorrect. As you are trying to assign a 2-D array to 1-D packed array. According to LRM either right-hand side should be 2-d like this.

```
  arr[1:0][1:0];
  assign arr = '{'{default:1}, '{default:0} }
```

or it should be

```
 assign arr = '{default:1}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is syntactically incorrect. You have an `assigment pattern` inside a concat `{}`. There is no assignment context there. You have to remove external braces:

```
assign arr = '{ default: arr_asgn[2] };
```